# xml - XSL html5 embed video

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-2.0

I would like to call a video in xsl document. I have an error. Do I need to create the template and call or other. Please give a sample I can look for it.

```
<video id='video' controls preload="none" poster="url" height="360">
     <source src="url" type="video/mp4
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source tag is not complete : you must close it.

```
<video id='video' controls preload="none" poster="url" height="360">
    <source src="url" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

I hope that helps you :)

Comment: `controls` is not XML syntax for a boolean attribute  so to have well-formed XML you need `<video id='video' controls="controls" preload="none" poster="url" height="360">`